# Magento 1.8: Set category url in store view level

Tags: magento-1.8, category, url, store-view

I have multiple websites (for each country) and each has one store view (different language). Currently categories have the same url for each store view. This, of course, brings some SEO problems.

Is it possible to set category url in store view level so we could have language specific category urls?

Comment: It seems that this has been fixed in later Magento versions and for example in 1.9.1.0. it is possible to set category url in store view level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer here: http://www.blog.plazathemes.com/archives/1846

> - First of all, access your Magento database from phpmyadmin (or any MySQL client).
> - Then run the following query:
>     SELECT * FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code LIKE ’%url_key%’;
>     Then you will have following results:
>     479 9   url_key NULL    catalog/category_attribute_backend_urlkey   varchar         text    URL key
>     481 10  url_key NULL    catalog/product_attribute_backend_urlkey    varchar         text    URL key
> - First attribute is for the category and second one is for the products. So note down the attribute_id of the first record (in my case 479).
> - Then run the following query:
>     SELECT attribute_id, is_global FROM catalog_eav_attribute WHERE attribute_id=479;
>     To make sure if it has ’1′ by default or not because ’1′ is the value to make the attribute GLOBAL.
> - If it is ’1′ then run the following query to update the value to ’0′:
>     UPDATE catalog_eav_attribute SET is_global=’0′ WHERE attribute_id=479;
> - Now clean the cache and try to edit a category with different stores and see the field URL Key. This will now have ‘Store View’ scope.